# Synonyms for 'Registration close date'

Tags: synonyms, syntactic-analysis

I'm managing an online registration to some conferences.
The conference coordinator has to add info about that in an online form, when submitting his conference to the registration website.

Is there a better way to describe the date the registration closes?

I prefer a short straight forward name.

PS. Yeah, I know you hate me, for this nerdy question, but in fact I face this question many times in other terms as well.

Comment: The  short and straight answer is historically most organisations didn't want to spend a lot of time clearing up confusion for applicants who couldn't distinguish between *date application is completed* (before being mailed), and *date application is **received***. So it was usually *"Applications must be **received** by [date]"*. Since yours is an online (instant) facility, you should probably use *"Applications must be **submitted** by [date]"*. But it might be wise to add *"at the latest"* to save people ringing up to ask if that final date is "inclusive" or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything wrong with "*deadline*"?

Answer (score 2):

How about simply

> registration ends

It's close to what you're saying already, but more commonly used. There's plenty of online examples:
[1](http://www.oregonlive.com/hillsboro/index.ssf/2014/07/harvest_century_bike_ride_earl.html) [2](http://www.smpsnerc.org/early-bird-registration-ends-february-28th/) [3](http://events.georgetown.edu/events/index.cfm?Action=View&EventID=101012) [4](http://www.newsnet5.com/sports/gay-games-registration-ends-monday-at-midnight) [5](http://www.chicagotribune.com/suburbs/elmhurst/community/chi-ugc-article-early-registration-ends-july-31st-for-3rd-ann-2014-07-21,0,3584878.story)